# What video games have been written only with C (not C++) language or/and Assembly language?

Tags: gaming-history

I am looking for video games that only contain Assembly language or/and C (not C++) language in their source code.

The best example of this that I can think of right now is RollerCoaster Tycoon (1999), as far as I know this game is written only Assembly language and the developer had to make an unusual effort to finish it.

It does not matter what genre or year the game is from, the only thing that matters is that it has been written with these languages, but if it is a 3D game much better.

Comment: Most NES, SNES, and Sega Genesis / Mega Drive games were written in Assembly or C.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad and asks for a large list of games. According to the site [tour] and the [help center on what types of questions are not allowed here](/help/dont-ask), questions that have "too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer" or that are not "reasonably scoped" are not allowed here.

Comment: This may be on-topic if you make it into a "What was the first game to...?" question instead.

Answer (score 3):

Many of id Software's early games are publicly available on [GitHub](https://github.com/id-Software) and meet your criteria:

- [Doom](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM)
- [Wolfenstein 3D](https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d)
- [Quake](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake)

All three of these games are written entirely in C with some Assembly sprinkled in.  These are probably some of the more famous examples given their influence on the gaming industry both at the time of their release, to present day.

As stated in the comments, many of the NES, SNES, Sega games were written in C or Assembly.  [Super Mario Bros. was written entirely in 6502 Assembly](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/what-programming-language-was-super-mario-bros-written-in) for example. Probably all NES/SNES games were written in Assembly, though I can't find a source indicating such (you can find lots of the source code online for these games indicating that they are in Assembly, but I'm not including links because I'm unsure of their legality).  Certainly the very early NES/SNES games were entirely written in Assembly.